# Unknown lifecycle phase "–-DskipTests=true" for Amazon Device Farm while Maven package

Tags: java, android, maven, amazon-web-services

I am trying to package sample-appium-test code from AWS Github.
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app

According to the [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html) of Amazon,
I have to package it with this command:

`mvn clean package –-DskipTests=true`

After that, I'm got this error

> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [INFO] Total time: 0.214 s
>
> [INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-30T09:02:33+08:00
>
> [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/155M
>
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "–-DskipTests=true". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

What should I do to fix this problem? Thanks you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `mvn clean package –DskipTests=true`, with a single '-'.

I believe it's a single '-' on OS X and '--' on Linux.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why a double-dash will return `Unknown lifecycle phase` but not `Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option`

Comment: I would like to ask if you know why should we skip test to package?

Comment: You could run the tests and package. The packaging instructions are to save time and only focus on getting the tests bundled for upload to device farm. If you run the tests and the package it, that is also perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It works when we use install instead of pkg

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

here is the link for your reference.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html